# ImportError: No module named 'PyQT5' Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, python-3.5, pyqt5

I wanted to do some Python3 Development.

I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

But it doesn't work:

python3

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14)
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQT5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQT5'
>>>
```

Comment: You must use: `import PyQt5`

Comment: Haha! Damn, that's evil! xD

Answer (score 2):

You need to pip install it :

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though one often reads "QT", the package name is not "PyQT5" but rather "PyQt5" with a lowercase 't' at the end.

Comment: Note that the [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)) pronunciation is "cute" too, though ;-)